# Conditional comment tags in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question:

I have phonegap app that I am currently building for iOS8, the only issue is that iOS8 deprecated some code for Pus Notifications, so in iOS8 i have gotten them to work but the code i use for it to work doesnt work in iOS7, im trying to get it to work for both. Im using an if else statement to check the version which is fine but the issue is that even though the if else only fires the correct version of the code, but in iOS7 my app wont compile correctly because it sees the newer code that doesnt exist in the iOS7 SDK, is there some way I can make this work? Like how you can do coniditional comments in HTML for specific browser versions?

THis is what I have, as you see it is just an if else statement, but obviously it does not work on the iOS7 SDK as that SDK doesnt know what the code in the initial (if) is since its new in iOS8

```
NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion   componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 8) {

    /// First register notification setting with settings type like
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; // you can also set here for local notification.

} else if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] < 8) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt.  Hint: objective C is pretty much a superset of C, including preprocessor directives like #ifdef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
//Put your iOS 8 code here
#else
// Put iOS 7 and below here
#endif
```